# Can I use Single Firebase account for two Google Play Developer account?

Tags: firebase, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I am having two Google play accounts one for games and one for apps.Can I use single Firebase account so that data of all my apps and games will be at one one place.

In short, I want to know,Can I use Single Firebase account for two Google Play Developer account?
is it legal?

Comment: What does it mean? They are not related.

Comment: I mean I am having two different google play accounts.Can I use single firebase account for the apps in both google play developers account. @GabrieleMariotti

Answer (score 2):

You can only link a Firebase Console project to a single Google Play project.

Depending on which features you're interested in, you may be able to get the data connected. The main data that flows directly between the two is some crash reporting information and in app purchase information. If that's the data you want, you can setup two Firebase project, and link both of them to BigQuery to combined the Firebase Analytics data there.

Comment: thank you @Ian Barber this information is really helpful for me. Currently I am having two different google play accounts one contains 5 apps and other 4 apps.I want to use single firebase account which will contain 9 projects(one per app as you mentioned).will it cause suspension to my account?,if I use single Firebase account for two google play accounts?